# display the elments in grid view in only one row

Tags: android, gridview

I want to display the grid view elements in only one row that means i want horizontal scrolling in grid view.Each time i want to display only 5 elements only in one row.For this give me some suggestions.Thanks in advance. 
below is the my layout code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/ImageViewlarge" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ImageView>
<TextView 

 android:id="@+id/TextViewImageName"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
  android:editable="false">
  </TextView>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:gravity="bottom" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/ImageViewLeft"
                       android:clickable="true"
                       android:focusable="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
                        android:src="@drawable/leftarrow" android:layout_height="50sp" android:layout_width="30sp" android:layout_gravity="bottom|left">
       </ImageView>
<GridView 
android:id="@+id/GridView01"
 android:scrollbars="horizontal" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal" 
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
     android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false" 
     android:numColumns="5" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="260sp">
 </GridView>
 <ImageView 
                     android:id="@+id/ImageViewRight" 
                     android:clickable="true"
                     android:focusable="true"                   
                     android:src="@drawable/rightarrow" android:layout_width="30sp" android:layout_height="50sp" android:layout_gravity="right"/>
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

in that above code now i want to remove the that 2 image view and set the horizontal scroll to that grid view elements.For this give me some suggestions,Thanks in advance

Comment: fyi, you might get more responses if you went back and accepted the answers to your previous questions as correct ;) Just click the check next to the answer that you believe best answered your question (if someone did in fact answer your question). You have a few questions that have good answers provided, but you have not accepted any of the provided answers on them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe the same effect could be achieved by using a `LinearLayout` with the orientation set to horizontal. The `LinearLayout` can be embedded in a [HorizontalScrollView](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)

The documentation on [HorizontalScrollView](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) actually says this:

> A HorizontalScrollView is a
>   FrameLayout, meaning you should place
>   one child in it containing the entire
>   contents to scroll; this child may
>   itself be a layout manager with a
>   complex hierarchy of objects. A child
>   that is often used is a LinearLayout
>   in a horizontal orientation,
>   presenting a horizontal array of
>   top-level items that the user can
>   scroll through.

Comment: i don't want scroll view.I want to display the total images(If i have 25 images) will be displayed in a single row.That is my qusetion.please give me some suggestion

Comment: sairam, why did you 'accept' my answer if it was not what you were looking for? Did it turn out that my answer worked for you, or are you still trying to figure out this issue but just clicked 'accept' accidentally?

Comment: @sairam it's confusing why you accepted this answer when it isn't what you asked in the question.

Comment: @Hamy guess he took your advice too literally by accepting every answer. :D